# Primefaces commandButton download complete hide dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In PrimeFaces 5.1 p:commandButton press to call download action. In action to get data from DB and create pdf. When its complete to download the pdf. My problem huge data create to taken a time that time I want to show dialog box, because user that time no for further action to done. CommandButton press I show dialog but can't know how to close dialog box.If any other way  to complete action to close dialog.

**stud.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="download" action="#{stud.downloadAction}" onclick="PF('progressWaitDialog').show()" ajax="false" onComplete="PF('progressWaitDialog').hide();"/>
<p:dialog id="progressWaitDialog" widgetVar="progressWaitDialog" modal="true">
<h:graphicImage value="#{stud.progressWaitBar}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

**stud.java**

```
public string downloadAction()
{
createPdf(studenToList);
return null;
}
```

My doubt commanButton click open dialog but download action complete how to hide dialog?

Comment: @Balus C I get records from db and do some change  to download so I can't use filedownload component?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PrimeFaces, you can take advantage of `PrimeFaces.monitorDownload` and `<p:fileDownload>`. It is documented [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml).

Basically, you have to change your `commandButton` to use an `actionListener` instead an `action`. This `actionListener`prepares an `org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent` to stream the file you want to download. This stream has to be wired with `value` attribute of `<p:fileDownload>`.

To prepare that `StreamedContent`, if your `createPdf(studenToList)` method returns a file, it would be as easy as following:

```
String mime = "application/pdf";
String name = "your-file-name.pdf";
File file = createPdf(studenToList);
StreamedContent stream = new DefaultStreamedContent(file, mime, name);
```

The `onclick` event of your `commandButton` will call the monitorDownload javascript of PrimeFaces `onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startFaDwn, stopFaDwn);"`.

Finally, you have to provide your own implementation of `startFaDown` and `stopFaDown`. This is mine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startFaDwn() {
        PF('FADownloadDlg').show();
    }

    function stopFaDwn() {
        PF('FADownloadDlg').hide();
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, both functions open and hide a dialog as you want. You can name these functions as you want, and obviously it can do what you want, not only open/close dialog.

You won't need `onComplete` event, neither `ajax="false"` attribute.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I use  in Stream content only support inputStream so I useStreamedContent stream = new DefaultStreamedContent(getInpustream(file), mime, name) that dialog hide but download file not working, I remove ajax dialog box not hide  and file not download

Comment: In File i set File file=new File("path of file stored");  and also I use InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("path of file stored"); both are not working